# Websphere 7.0.0.17 error with Pool Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jndi, websphere-7

Im having a problem with an application, I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.1 with oracle 11g, I'm getting a J2CA0045E error, because the pooling does not set free any connections pool from the jndi,

Have you have this problem?, apparently the connection does not get released and it reach the limit I've configured.

Any ideas, this is my Connection pool

```
Connection timeout: 180
Maximum connections: 10
Minimum connections: 1
Reap time: 60
Unused timeout: 180
Aged timeout: 120
Purge policy: Entire Pool
```

**EDIT**

I have a web service in the same service, and the behavior is the same, using same jndi, the connection increase and does not release any connection

```
initCtx = new InitialContext(); 
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/abc");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: this could be caused by many different things.  Post relevant parts of your java code to show us how you are using connections.  Are you using shareable connections?

Comment: I add info, please let me know if you have any idea! @aguibert

Comment: You are probably leaking connections.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, it looks like you are storing the `Connection` reference at a class scope.  You should avoid storing references to `Connection` objects that could span multiple requests.

Instead, store a reference to the `DataSource`.

To illustrate.  This approach is preferred:

```
public class GoodService {

    DataSource ds;

    public GoodService() throws NamingException {
        // Only the DataSource reference is stored, this is allowed
        ds = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/abc");
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        // Get the connection in a request.
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        try {
            // do something...
        } finally {
            // Always close the connection in the finally block
            // so it gets returned to the pool no matter what
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The following approach is considered bad practice, and is likely to cause the J2CA0045E error you are seeing:

```
public class BadService {

    Connection conn; // BAD: don't store a Connection across requests!

    public BadService() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        DataSource ds = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/abc");
        // BAD: don't leave connections open indefinitely like this
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        // do something using conn...
    }
}
```